# 12テーブルをINNER JOINしているSQL文(コードあり)の速度改善をしたいです。LEFT OUTER JOINに変えたりしておりますが、改善につながりません。

Tags: mysql, sql

次のようなSQL文があります。
こちらのSQLでは、INNER JOINしているテーブル及び、WHERE文で対象としているテーブルは、２つしかありません。
これでしたら10秒ほどで、集計が完了します。

しかし、今回の要件上、INNER JOINするテーブル数は、12個あり、
同様にINNER JOINとWHERE文を追加していき実行すると、1時間以上かかってしまいます。

```
SELECT artists.user_id, artists.staff_id,
Sum(events.sum),\
Sum(goods.sum),\
FROM artists\
INNER JOIN `events` ON `artists`.`id` = `events`.`artist_id`\
INNER JOIN `goods` ON `artists`.`id` = `goods`.`artist_id`\ 
WHERE (`events`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-07-30')\
AND (`goods`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-07-30')\
GROUP BY artists.user_id, artists.staff_id;
```

SQLの速度改善をしたいのですが、これ以上絞り込む条件がないため、
SQL文の見直しにより、改善できる方法を探しております。

尚、バッチ処理にするという案は今回の要件上NGでした。

生のSQL文で記述しておりますが、実際はRuby on Railsのアプリケーション上で実行します。
その為、非同期処理というのも模索しておりますが、今回、集計した結果をDBにINSERTするため、
非同期処理にすると、本来データが入ってほしいレコードにデータが入らないという恐れを懸念しております。

INNER JOIN を LEFT OUTER JOIN にしたり等、不勉強ながら試行錯誤しておりますが、なかなか改善につながりません。

理想は1~2分で完了してほしいです。

また、この集計処理は、期間を変えて実行することはあっても、同じSQL文を何度も使うということはないので、
クエリキャッシュをするというのもあまり意味がないと思っております。

また、外部キー周りにindexキーはつけております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 広く回答を募りたいため、勝手ながらこちらにも投稿しております。https://teratail.com/questions/86234?modal=q-comp

Comment: JOINが絡むSQL文の速度改善といっても、JOINされるテーブルとの関係が、1対1なのか1対多なのか多対1なのか、またそれぞれのデータ件数はどの程度なのかによって基本的な方策も適切なインデッスクのかけたも大きく異なるのですが、あなたのご質問ではその辺りが不明確です。(単に「外部キー周りにindexキーはつけております」では、そのインデックスのかけ方が適切なのかどうかがわかりません。)あなたのSQLを読む限り`events`と`goods`は`artists`に対して1対多であろうことが推定されるのですが、このような場合、JOINに際して作成される内部表の大きさが組み合わせ論的に爆発する(用はレコード数が掛け算で増えていく)ことが性能に大きく影響します。レコード数の目安さえ示されていない(SQL文を改善したいのなら、その辺の情報はご質問に含めていただいた方が良いでしょう)ので大ハズレの可能性もありますが、ご質問に掲載のSQL文の実行に10秒程度かかると言うのは幾ら何でも遅すぎるように感じます。user20098 さんが示されたように、実行計画などを参照して、まずはJOINするテーブルが2個のSQLを徹底的にチューニングしてみられてはいかがでしょうか。ちなみにINNER JOINをLEFT JOINに変えることで速度改善できるなんてことはほとんどなく、かえって遅くなることも多いです。

Comment: 提示された情報で有効な速度改善方法を解凍できる人間は存在しないでしょう。テーブル構造（制約、インデックスを含む）と、各テーブルの手コード数くらいは最低限必要可かと思います。

Answer (score 2):

ご希望の回答ではありませんが、実行するSQL文に対し`EXPLAIN`すると「実行計画」が出力されるので、どこの記述(検索条件、結合、etc.)に時間がかかっているかわかると思います。

＃Oracleの場合「`EXPLAIN PLAN`」、PostgreSQLの場合「`EXPLAIN ANALYE`」、MySQLだと「`EXPLAIN`」と微妙に文法が異なりますが、「実行計画」が取得できる点は一緒です。

例: PostgreSQLの場合:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT artists.user_id, artists.staff_id,
Sum(events.sum),\
Sum(goods.sum),\
FROM artists\
INNER JOIN `events` ON `artists`.`id` = `events`.`artist_id`\
INNER JOIN `goods` ON `artists`.`id` = `goods`.`artist_id`\ 
WHERE (`events`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-07-30')\
AND (`goods`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-07-30')\
GROUP BY artists.user_id, artists.staff_id;
```

`EXPLAIN`の結果を見て「遅い」箇所を突き止めるのがよいかと思います。